# Web content such as Images not showing up in Google App Engine Proxy?

Tags: html, google-app-engine

I am making a Proxy with Google App Engine (GAE) and I am running into a problem.
I have added this to my `app.yaml`;

```
application: APPNAME
version: secureable
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /robots\.txt
  static_files: static/robots.txt
  upload: static/robots\.txt

- url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|js|css|swf|php))
  static_files: \1
  upload: (.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|js|css|swf|php))

- url: /images\.ico
  static_files: images/db_favicon.ico
  upload: images/db_favicon\.ico

- url: /static
  static_dir: static
  secure: optional

- url: /.*
  script: mirror.app
  secure: optional
```

As you can see that it has all of the general stuff, however I have recently added;

```
    - url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|js|css|swf|php))
      static_files: \1
      upload: (.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|js|css|swf|php))
```

Which has made all of the webpage images disappear as well as all of the formatting/css. Well, it only returns the HTML and that is it. The error has only occured when I added this but I want SWF files and other things to work (like GIF's and other stuff). - Thanks

Comment: Are your static files in a directory?  For example, where is your main css file?  According to your code, your /something.css file would need to be found at the root level.

Comment: Well that is the thing. Do I need a file for each one? All I know is that I have a `static` folder and inside there is `robots.txt`? I am not to sure if I need extra files or something.

Comment: Where are your css, swf, js, gif files now?  And, what urls are you using to access them?  For example, site.com/image.gif, or site.com/static/image.gif ?

Comment: Oh right, I did not know about that. I just looked at it and tried to implement it into mine. How would I go about make SWF, GIF and all the other files work? And would I need to "create" files? I am not to sure - Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is my advice.  Delete the regex stuff:

```
- url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|js|css|swf|php))
  static_files: \1
  upload: (.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|js|css|swf|php))
```

Put all your static files (gif, swf, css, jpg, js,etc) into the static directory, and access them using `/static/filename.ext`.  (filename means whatever filename you use, and ext means whatever extension for the file, like gif, css, etc.)  Do not use regex until you understand what it is doing.  For a simple site, using a simple static directory is a clean solution.

Comment: Oh right. So I can just put the `.ext` files in my static directory? Then remove the regex (the `-url:/` stuff)?

Comment: Wait a minute.  I see a PHP extension in your regex.  Are you running a php or Python app?  Your code should work as-is, if your static images are at the root level.  Where are your static files?

Comment: I am running Python. And do you mind saying a small explanation of this "static" stuff because I think I get it but I am not 100% sure on it? Because I do not have any "static images"? - Thanks

Comment: Anything with these extensions is a static file:  gif|png|jpg|ico|js|css|swf .

Comment: Oh right. So would I have to create separate `.ext` files for each one so that they can run on my proxy?

Comment: NO!  There is no such thing as a .ext file.  Put any files that end in gif|png|jpg|ico|js|css|swf in your static directory, and access them using /static/filename.gif ( or .swf, or .jpg, or .css, etc). Bye

Comment: Hmm, it is not loading SWF files, is this because it needs to be able to run flashplayer?

Comment: That requires a separate question, as it is outside the scope of this question.  http://bit.ly/1G3XgFN

Comment: Oh right. I made a separate question for it. However I am not sure that that is what I am looking for is it? I am not to sure really?